# bower config use svn

Tags: git, svn, bower

i successfully installed bower and now i want to use bower with svn+ command. Like this:

```
bower install svn+https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap --save
```

actully this would work, but the bootstrap package automaticly starts installing the jquery package, but without `svn+`.

Error message:

```
bower bootstrap#*           not-cached svn+https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#*
bower bootstrap#*              resolve svn+https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#*
bower bootstrap#*               export v3.3.2
bower bootstrap#*             resolved https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#3.3.2
bower jquery#>= 1.9.1       not-cached https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#>= 1.9.1
bower jquery#>= 1.9.1          resolve https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#>= 1.9.1
bower jquery#>= 1.9.1          ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git", exit code of #128
```

So i was wondering if der is a way to use `svn+` as default?

PS: I'm not allowed to use git because of security issuses in our company

Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the soulution...

If package has a dependency, i just need to download the dependency first. In my example:

```
bower install svn+https://github.com/jquery/jquery --save
```

Answer (score 1):

You managed to install the Bootstrap package this way since Github [supports](https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/) Subversion clients. Bower identifies the URL you are using as an SVN repo and uses the [SvnResolver](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/lib/core/resolvers/SvnResolver.js) which uses the SVN client.
It start failing when Bower resolves the dependencies of Bootstrap.
Most of the packages (or all of them) registered in the Bower registry are stored in Github repositories. Bower is using git to resolve the package from Github repositories. When the Bower client is resolving the Bootstrap dependencies, for example jQuery, it will get the repository URL from the registry and this URL will point to Github.

I don't think there is a way to configure Bower to rewrite the URLs it gets from the registry.